# Yield Curve Bootstrapping with FRAs (Excel without QuantLib)

Tags: bootstrapping

I am trying to bootstrap a 6m Euribor curve using the same instruments as the default Bloomberg curve:

6m Euribor rate, 12 FRAs starting at 1x7 finishing at 12X18, Swap rates 2yrs each year out to 10yrs (no need to go any further out).

How do I do the first iteration of the bootstrapping to get the spot rate and spot discount factor for the 1x7 FRA?

I have the spot rate and discount factor for the 6m Euribor rate and the FWD discount factor for for the 1x7 FRA - what else do I need and what is the next calculation step please?

I can bootstrap a curve from just the swap rates but I don't know how I add in the FRAs
Sorry if this is obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

- $F(t,t+\tau)$ be the forward rate from time t to t + $\tau$
- $D(t)$ the discount factor for time t

The forward rate will be given by:

$$ 1 + F(t, t + \tau) \tau = \frac{D(t)}{D(t + \tau)}$$

So in your case you have (more or less):

$$1 + FRA_{1x7} \times 182/360 = \frac{D_{1M}}{D_{7M}}$$

and in your process of bootstrapping the yield curve you are expecting to solve for the $D_{7M}$. However, you have a problem because you also don't know the $D_{1M}$

You could, in a very naive way, interpolate between $D_{0}=1$ and $D_{6M}$ which you already know to get a 1M pseudo discount factor, and use that to solve for the $D_{7M}$.

This is an outdated approach and will lead to unsmooth forwards but it will allow you to start with simpler procedures and go from there. For a more correct and advanced approach I suggest this presentation [The abcd of Forward Rate Bootstrapping](https://speakerdeck.com/nando1970/the-abcd-of-forward-rate-bootstrapping)

Notice that on Bloomberg you can choose several interpolation methods (Smooth forward, Piecewise Linear, etc) that will give slighly different results. By default I believe you would have "Smooth Forward (Cont)", where, according to Bloomberg documentation:

"*Continuously compounded forward rate. The forward rate rcf defined by the formula is piecewise quadratic. The neighboring points of the forward curve are connected in such a way that the first derivative of the forward rate is continuous, which is reflected in the term "smooth." The building of the curve requires the global pricing method.*"

On this, I would suggest the paper Methods for Constructing a Yield Curve by Hagan and West.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I am assuming that your FRA is **not** settled in arrears, i.e. the (forward) LIBOR rate is settled at $t>t_0$ and paid at $t+\tau$.

The present value formula for this FRA is:

\begin{align}
PV&=N\tau D_{OIS}(t+\tau)\left[R(t_0,t,t+\tau)-F(t,t+\tau)\right]\\
&=N\tau D_{OIS}(t+\tau)\left[R(t_0,t,t+\tau)-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(\frac{D_{6M}(t)}{D_{6M}(t+\tau)}-1\right)\right]
\end{align}

and hence your FRA-implied theoretical discount factor for (any) tenor should equal

$$
D_{6M}(t+\tau)=D_{6M}(t)\frac{1}{1+\tau R(t_0,t,t+\tau)}
$$

Again, this implies knowledge of or an interpolation assumption for the first tenor(s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I’m still in the dark here.. Is there a resource that details the notation you are using? Sorry if it is standard - i'm new to this.

Comment: Today is Fri 2nd Oct
I have the 6m EURIBOR rate (-0.481% today) so the discount factor is 1.00243765 (calc: 1/(1-0.481%*182/360))
the 1x7 FRA resets on 4th Nov, Settles on 6th Nov and matures on 6th May 2021 (181 days after settle dt).
How would I match your notation to get the spot discount factor and Zero rate for 6th May 2021?